# How do i print a variable back into my function?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add the total costs of a users input via gets.chomp and then put that back into the function so it prints outs the total costs at the end of the function. Am i doing this right?

```
def costs_of_company(hosting, design, phones, total_costs)
  puts "Total costs are as follows: \n"
  puts "Hosting costs $#{hosting}."
  puts "Design would cost $#{design}."
  puts "The cost for 100 Phones would be $#{phones}."
  puts "Total costs are #{total_costs}"
end

puts "Tell me the costs of your company. \n"
puts "hosting \n"
hosting = gets.chomp
puts "design \n"
design = gets.chomp
puts "phones \n"
phones = gets.chomp
total_costs = hosting + design + phones  #I think i am way off here.

costs_of_company(hosting, design, phones)
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to pass in the `total_costs` variable to your function call of `costs_of_company` at the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the line `total_costs = hosting + design + phones` is that input is in String format. That would work if you did `total_costs = hosting.to_i + design.to_i + phones.to_i`

This is assuming all inputs are integers. Alternatively, use `.to_f` if you want to use decimals (floats).

Furthermore, you can also do `hosting = gets.chomp.to_i`, `design = gets.chomp.to_i`, and `phones = gets.chomp.to_i`

However, now we enter the realm of how do we know if the user gave us good input? The default behavior of `.to_i` is to default to zero if the input is not an integer e.g. `"hello".to_i == 0`. This is fine for most cases.

A more sophisticated approach would be to make a function that handles the user input so that you can sanitize everything in one place, AND handle errors. For example if you wanted to use `Integer()` instead of `.to_i` you would need to catch errors because an exception is thrown for invalid input with integer. Here is an example of using a regular expression to sanitize the input with exception handling.

```
def get_input
  while true
    begin
      input = gets.chomp.match(/d+/)[0]
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "that is not a valid integer. Please try again"
    else
      return input
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in depth breakdown and analysis. I will study the things you've outlined and move forward.

Comment: No problem! If this was the answer you were looking for, make sure to click the checkmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I would use .to_f for money to keep track of cents and print it a bit prettier.  Here's a debugged version:

```
def print_money(val)
  format('%.2f',val)
end

def costs_of_company(hosting, design, phones)
  puts "Total costs are as follows: \n"
  puts "Hosting costs $#{print_money(hosting)}."
  puts "Design would cost $#{print_money(design)}."
  puts "The cost for 100 Phones would be $#{print_money(phones)}."
  total_costs = hosting + design + phones
  puts "Total costs are $#{print_money(total_costs)}"
end

puts "Tell me the costs of your company. \n"
puts "hosting \n"
hosting = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "design \n"
design = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "phones \n"
phones = gets.chomp.to_f

costs_of_company(hosting, design, phones)
```

Comment: def print_money(val)
    format('%.2f',val)
  end

What was happening there in this function. %.2f is that number to float?